EASA Regulations regarding Private Aircraft for PPL training
Can somebody advise what are the EASA specific regulations that apply regarding the use of a privately registered aircraft for PPL training? Links in particular to the EASA website would be greatly helpful.
Many thanks!

mind that ALL aircraft not registered to government agencies are privately registered. So if privately registered aircraft weren't allowed to be used for flight training, only the government would be able to provide flight training!

Each country participating to EASA has its own air authorities and local rules. Some rules are already common at EASA level, found in the Standardized European Rules of the Air, SERA.
As an example of national rules: For France, rules are edicted by DGAC, and published by SIA, the ICAO AIP manager. The link between EASA and French rules is described in this SIA document (in French). A consolidated document, SERA Complet includes both SERA and local rules. This structure may be different in other EASA State members. EASA is not the same geographic scope as EU.
SERA and related documents all related documents are named "Easy-something", but their structure with endless links is confusing and they are difficult to use due to their bureaucratic jargon, nothing in common with US CFR. Still, my gest guest is the aircraft requirements for PPL training are found in:

Easy Access Rules for Organisation Requirements for Aircrew (Part-ORA), in particular AMC1 ORA.ATO.135 Training aircraft and FSTDs.

Easy Access Rules for Declared Training Organisations (Part-DTO), in particular DTO.GEN.240 Training aircraft and FSTDs and following paragraphs.

Acceptable Means of Compliance and Guidance Material to Part-FCL.


EASA has a homepage for GA, I suggest to join their community and ask there for details.
